# Jwplayer 6: html5 fullscreen when video clicked to play

Tags: ios, html, video, jwplayer, android-fullscreen

I want to be able to use jwplayer so that when the user clicks on the video the video will start to play in fullscreen mode.

I want this functionality to work on mobile devices that support html5.

If the video is played on a mobile device it will take up the whole screen.
Youtube and Vimeo currently do this on mobile devices.

The Link Below uses Html5 video tag, which plays in fullscreen on mobile device when the video is clicked on.

The only way I that I know that jwplayer allows fullscreen is that I manually click on the fullscreen button, but it would be nice to only click on the video to trigger the video to play in full screen.

Comment: Actually, this the default for us as well. Check this link on an iPhone - http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/download/, it will play in fullscreen mode when play is pressed.

Comment: @EthanLongTail Does that feature only work on the iPhone? When I went to the link with my android it did not go fullscreen.

Comment: It depends on the size of the device. It if it an iPad, it will player in browser, or a bigger Android tablet, but if you use an Android phone, or an iPod Touch, or an iPhone, it will launch fullscreen by default. I tested that link above on a Samsung Galaxy II and it launches fullscreen when play is pressed. Do you have Flash installed on your Android?

Comment: @EthanLongTail Is it possible to play videos (youtube) without automatic fullscreen in Jwplayer on mobile devices? Is there a option for that? I want to play videos without fullscreen.

Comment: @emaxasun -it may be silly question but can you explain why are we going to full screen in iPhone. Do we not have support for jwplayer controls in iPhone ?